# como usar a função POW (POTENCIA) em C

Tags: c

Boa tarde galera, ja cheguei ate aqui.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
float val_carro, juros_mensal = juros_mensal / 100, num_parcelas, cf;

printf("\n\n  Digite o valor do carro: "); //entrada variaveis
scanf("%f", &val_carro);
printf("\n  Digite o numero de parcelas: ");
scanf("%f", &num_parcelas);
printf("\n  Digite o juros mensal: ");
scanf("%f", &juros_mensal);

cf = (1 + juros_mensal);
cf = (cf pow num_parcelas);  // calculo coeficiente de financiamento
cf = (1 / cf);
cf = (1 - cf);
cf = (juros_mensal / cf);

printf("\n\n  O valor de cada parcela é: %f", cf); //exibe valor de cada parcela
printf("\n\n  O valor do carro é: %f", cf *= 3); // exibe valor total do carro
return 0;
}
```

so que na linha que esta comentada o coeficiente de financiamento, da erro,

*expected')' before 'num_parcelas'*

entao nao to conseguindo solucionar isso.

Comment: não seria assim? cf = (pow (cf,num_parcelas));

Comment: entao eu ja fiz assim isolei todas as variaves junto, e separado da função e o erro persiste

Comment: `pow` é uma função do C, não um operador. Para utilizá-lo, como falou o @Diego, é necessário chamá-la como uma função da seguinte forma: `pow(base, expoente)`.

Comment: agora consegui eu deixei um espaço no meio e nao tinha rodado dava erro, mas corrigi agora. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Vou postar a resposta, para ficar registrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linha tem um erro de sintaxe:

```
 cf = (pow(cf,num_parcelas));
```

Onde:

```
pow(base, expoente);
```

Comment: Obrigado @Diego mas ja consegui resolver o problema e sim estava errado mesmo.